# Is it possible to import wordpress website pages in angular js?

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

### I want to convert a wordpress website into a mobile app.

Recently I found ionic and angular js courses and their services through which we can call posts and other rest api stuff.

My question is how can I import the whole wordpress website pages into angular js or any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wordpress plugin to convert your wordpress site into a mobile app.

here is a link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordapp-mobile-app/

Also you can visit here: https://wordpress.org/mobile/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i already try this one but we need more customization and control over the app.